# Django blows up with 1.1, Can't find urls module

Tags: python, django, django-1.1

EDIT: Issue solved, answered it below. Lame error. Blah

So I upgraded to Django 1.1 and for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm missing. Here is my traceback:

http://dpaste.com/37391/ - This happens on any page I try to go to.

I've modified my urls.py to include the admin in the new method:

> from django.contrib import admin
>
> admin.autodiscover()
>
> .... urlpatterns declaration
>
> (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

I've tried fidgeting with paths and the like but nothing fixes my problem and I can't figure it out.

Has something major changed since Django 1.1 alpha -> Django 1.1 beta that I am missing? Apart from the admin I can't see what else is new. Are urls still stored in a urls.py within each app?

Thanks for the help in advance, this is beyond frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing a urls.py that I referenced (for some reason, SVN said it was in the repo but it never was fetched on an update) and it simply said could not find urls (with no reference to notes.urls which WAS missing) so it got very confusing.

Either way, fixed -- Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
```

[More info](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges#Mergednewforms-adminintotrunk)

Comment: From what I understand, that is the old method of doing it. The one I show is how its done in Django 1.1 ... unless I am reading something wrong.

Also, I tried what you suggested and same issue.

Comment: You're using SVN versione or the package from the website?

Comment: Yeah that is the older way of doing it. It is deprecated, but still works for now.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of your ROOT_URLCONF in your settings.py file? Is the file named by that setting on your python path?

Are you using the development server or what?